# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded MPDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

Quando executa local o PDF gera normalmente, porem no servidor ele da tempo de limite excedido e não abre.

```
<?php 

        require_once "../mpdf60/mpdf.php";
        require_once "../DAO/conexao.php";
        require_once "../DAO/vendaDAO.php";
        session_start();

        $vend = $_SESSION["vendedor_nome"];


        if (isset($_GET["orcamento"]) && isset($_GET["data"]) && isset($_GET["cliente"]) && isset($_GET["totalprod"]) && isset($_GET["email"]))
        {
                $orcamento = $_GET["orcamento"];
                $data = $_GET["data"];
                $cliente = $_GET["cliente"];
                $totalprod = $_GET["totalprod"];
                $email = $_GET["email"];

                $dao = new VendaDAO();
                $venda = $dao->GetByIdRel($_GET["orcamento"]);
                $itens = $venda->getItensRel($venda);

                foreach($itens as $item)
                {

                    $formaPagamento = $item->getCusto($row->FPG_DESCRICAO);
                }




                $html = " 

                <hr> </hr>
                <div id='img'> <img src='../css/logo.png' align='center' height='100px' width='220px' ></div>
                 <div id='teste'>
                        <td> Rua X, y 
                        Centro - CIDADE/UF 
                        CEP: 10000-000 <br/>
                        (00) 3333.3333 | E-mail
                        EMAIL@EMAIL.com.br
                     </div>
                    <hr> </hr>
                    <p align='center'><b> DADOS DA VENDA </b></p>
                    <p></p>


                                    Número do Pedido: $orcamento <br/>
                    Data da Venda: $data  <br/>
                                    Vendedor: $vend <br/>
                                    Cliente: $cliente <br/>
                                    Email: $email <br/>
                                    Forma de Cobrança: $formaPagamento  <br/>
                                    Total Produtos: $totalprod <br/>    
                                    <hr> </hr>    
                    <p align='center'><b> DADOS DO PRODUTO </b></p>



                    <table border=1 align='center' cellspacing='0'>
                    <tr>
                    <td><b>PRODUTO</b></td>
                    <td><b>DESCRIÇÃO</b></td>
                                    <td><b>QUANTIDADE</b></td>
                                    <td><b>VALOR</b></td>
                    <td><b>TOTAL</b></td>";




                                 foreach($itens as $item)  
                                 {
                                        $produto = $item->getProduto();

                                            $html= $html ."<tr>
                                            <td>{$item->getProduto($row->PRO_CODIGO)}</td>
                                            <td>{$item->getReservado($row->PRO_DESCRICAO)}</td>
                                            <td>{$item->getQuantidade($row->ORI_QTDE)}</td>
                                            <td>{$item->getValor($row->ORI_VALOR)}</td>
                                            <td>{$item->getTotal($total)}</td>
                        </tr>";
                                 }
                    $html = $html . "</table>";




                                    $mpdf=new mPDF(); 
                                    $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
                                    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
                                    $css = file_get_contents("css/estilo.css");
                                    $mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);
                                    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                                    $mpdf->Output();

        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Tente usar `ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);` e veja se pode ser usado como solução. Coloque-o bem no cabeçalho do código. O ideal é você alterar no php.ini, por questões de padronização (PSR).

Comment: Perfeito cara, funcionou aqui com o meu. Obrigado e parabéns

Answer (score 2):

Coloque no começo do arquivo `set_time_limit(0);`

`set_time_limit`  define um tempo máximo para a execução de um script, porém se você definir como 0 nenhum limite é definido.

(veja a [documentação do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-time-limit.php))

Comment: Coloquei set_time_limit(0); e funcionou, mas está demorando cerca de 50 segundos para executar.. Tem algum método que deixa essa execução mais rápida? Isso ocorre porque a biblioteca é pesada?

Comment: @B.Noe com relação a velocidade é um pouco mais complicado porque existem "N" possibilidade de coisas que possam fazer o código ficar mais lento, desde biblioteca a configuração de servidor.

Mas se esta resposta te ajuda por favor marque como resolvido! :)